# https to http redirect through htaccess for specific page only

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Though it may looks like a very common question, but nothing is worked for me.  Below is my problem.

I need to redirect my domain from http to https through htaccess. (I found the code and it is worked fine for me). But at the same, i do not want to redirect to https for some video pages on my site (http://www.ptchoices.com/welcome/video/467f9fd9-d649-4910-923e-83eeccd13875). because of previously written redirect rule, it tends to endless redirect loop.

Please suggest me on the same.

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133599/redirect-http-to-https-for-one-page. It seems to have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check to see if you're already on https before you redirect. If https is not on, it won't redirect. I believe this is what you're requesting.  If not, i'll modify my answer.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: i already checked with this will redirect all pages from http to https. But i do not want to redirect my video to https.