# HTTPS only on specific pages - Htaccess, Apache, OpenSSL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

I'm trying to get HTTPS to work as I want, but with no luck.
What I like to do is that I want the website to go over http, and https on specific url's. The specific url's is: reg.php & glomtpass.php.

But when I try the code, it says: "This webpage has a redirect loop". After a bunch of attempts it still have that error.

The HTTP -> HTTPS code I use in .htacess right now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/(reg|glomtpass)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure but looking at the highlighting here, does the // in your Rewrite Rule need to be escaped?

Comment: do you have a functions file you require on all pages? (if so i have a great solution for you not involving rewrites)

Comment: @Mic1780 I don't have a function file on all pages right now, but I can start using one

Comment: If you have SSL why not use it on all pages?

Comment: @ceejayoz Because some scripts have problems to send and receive information over SSL. That's why I only want some pages to be forced to use SSL

Comment: I suppose you have some more rules that do the opposite thing, and redirect from HTTP to HTTPS? If so, and they don’t make an exemption for the URLs you are rewriting here in the code shown … then of course that’ll lead to an endless redirect …

Comment: @Hampeee Fix the scripts, then.

Comment: @ceejayoz It's not my scripts, it's from Google

Comment: @Hampeee I severely doubt Google's scripts don't work on HTTPS. Care to provide the script you're working with so we can help you troubleshoot?

Comment: I talked to a Google Expert who's a family friend, and he said that Google have problems for the moment with some scripts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for one page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133599/redirect-http-to-https-for-one-page). (This question has been asked so many times I've lost count).

Comment: @Hampeee: *"Because some scripts have problems to send and receive information over SSL. That's why I only want some pages to be forced to use SSL"* - that subjects you and your users to [stripping attacks](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-dc-09/Marlinspike/BlackHat-DC-09-Marlinspike-Defeating-SSL.pdf). Bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

If it is not too much trouble to add a functions file to the top of your pages then this is how I check move in and out of HTTPS in php. To use it just require the file you put this in on all your scripts.

**functions file**

```
<?php

$scriptsWithSSL = array('reg.php','glomtpass.php');
if (in_array(end(explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])), $scriptsWithSSL) === true) {
    //we are on a page we want to be HTTPS. will become HTTPS if requested with HTTP
    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off') {
        header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        exit;
    }
} else {
    //page should not be HTTPS and will move to HTTP if requested with HTTPS
    if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on') {
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

What this will do is any script that is found inside the `$scriptsWithSSL` array with be moved to HTTPS if it is not requested with HTTPS. Otherwise its a normal page and will be moved from HTTPS to HTTP if it was not requested with HTTP.

Comment: I'm really thankful for your help, but the last one did not work either. It works on IE 11.0.9 but not on Google Chrome or Opera

Comment: Can you give me a link to the page with the problem?

Comment: Oh do you have have those rewrite rules on? That might be causing the infinite loop.

Comment: They are turned off with "#"

Comment: Is the infinite loop occuring when switching from HTTP to HTTPS or vice versa?

Comment: From HTTPS to HTTP. And then when I try to refresh the page it's still the same. So I have to close my browser, open it and then go back to the website again

Comment: This makes no sense. When it enters the else case it checks to see if HTTPS is on and if it is then turn it off with a redirect. There should be no reason it is infinitely looping with my code. I even tried it on my server in Chrome and it works fine.

Comment: Did you try to browse on my website to see the problem for yourself?

Comment: Yeah. As of right now it is not changing from https to http. maybe you disabled it so when its enabled let me know.

Comment: Nothing is disabled. The function is using your code, so nothing is disabled, added or deleted. That's really strange...

I looked around in the code. Can't "$_SERVER['HTTPS']" be "$_SERVER['HTTP_HTTPS']" ?

Comment: No. Refer to $_SERVER documentation at http://us1.php.net/reserved.variables.server.php Also you told me that `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` echoed "on" when you disabled my code. so it should only echo "on" when HTTPS is actually on

Comment: Currect. It echoed "on" with the script off. When I turned it on again, that's where the loop trubble is coming

Comment: Hm, maybe I should test with just one array instead of 2

Comment: Can you pastebin the file that use are using my code in please?

Comment: I added faq.php as an array, and its the same problem..
http://pastebin.com/JWmmyG6K

Comment: Can you pastebin the include/httpsfunctions.php file. Thats the one i have interest in

Comment: Is the include folder inside the global folder or is it in the root directory?

Comment: The root folder. I disabled the Language Detection Redirect so you only viewing the "main site".

Comment: Right now everything on your site is being redirected to https. So whatever is causing this to happen is conflicting with the include

Comment: Not on the main site. I've disabled the Language Detection so you won't be redirected to /global/. On the main site I'm using your code, and it's there it fails for some reason

Comment: Oh ok i see it now. So what im seeing is that the redirects are working but something in apache is then redirecting it back to https and my script then forces it back to http and its an endless loop. So something in your rewrites is still causing the problem. F12 in Chrome will show you this in the Network tab

Comment: http://2imgs.com/2i/i/5400fc8f/e4501e51398d9bee102cbb0d422ca52a/98cc6b4192.f.png  that's how it looks

Comment: There is not much more I can do to help with this. The issue is with an apache rewrite since it works on my site and yours causes an infinite loop. Here is an image of what I see when I get the loop problem. Notice the initiator and status codes for each redirect. (if its blurry they are 302 status codes and initiators are alternating between https to http)http://imgur.com/cL7DknP

Comment: I will get a closer look into it tomorrow. I can try to delete all https redirect code from .htaccess and see what happens. A very big thank you so far with all help. I will update you tomorrow if there's any change.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60303/discussion-on-answer-by-mic1780-https-only-on-specific-pages-htaccess-apache).

Comment: @bluefeet We could not move this to chat because OP does not have the rep to do so.

Comment: @Mic1780 They should be able to chat now via my migration.